# Problem With Regards to Change of Parameters after Insertion of a Di-Electric in a Capacitor

Tags: capacitance, dielectric

I came across this problem where we had to calculate the maximum charge that can be accumulated on the plates of a capacitor (containing a di-electric) before the di-electric breaks down due to the electric field.
Here is the question

> A parallel plate capacitor with plate area $100 cm^2$ separated by a distance of $1mm$. A di-electric of di-electric constant $5$ and di-electric strength $1.9 * 10^7$ V/m is filled between plates. Find the maximum charge that can be stored on the capacitor without causing any di-electric breakdown.

Here was my approach
[image]

Note that the value of charge thus obtained is independent of K.

After plugging in the values I get the value of charge as $1.6*10^-6$ C, while the answer is $8.4*10^-6$ C. The answers differ by a factor of K=5(the di-electric constant). I am not sure why this is happening.

Kindly express your respective insights regarding the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your second formula should be $V=Ed$

Comment: But why ?
Assume that we have applied an electric field required to breakdown the di-electric but with slightly less magnitude. If the di-electric is present, then due to the induced electric field produced by the di-electric, won't the net electric field be reduced to E(break)/k ? And then the potential difference across the plates corresponding to this field would be E(break)*d/k.

Comment: @ Parth, hi, the way to look at is is that the electric field caused by a voltage is $E=\frac{V}{d}$, the voltage caused by a given charge is reduced by the relative permittivity (as the capacitance is higher), but once that voltage is reached (by the higher charge than usual) the dielectric breaks down.

Comment: I didn’t quite get that. Can you please elaborate upon the Voltage part.

Comment: @ Parth  you wrote "Assume that we have applied an electric field required to breakdown the di-electric but with slightly less magnitude. If the di-electric is present, then due to the induced electric field produced by the di-electric, won't the net electric field be reduced"  that is true, and so then the charge must be increased again to bring the electric field back up to the value that causes the breakdown, but in the end for breakdown the electric field must have the value $1.9 \times 10^7$V/m

Comment: But still how would you justify that V=Ed is correct ?

Comment: Work done on a charge is force x distance $W=Fd\tag1$ $W=QV$ and $F=EQ$ so 1) becomes $QV=EQ\times d$, so $V=Ed$, all the best with it.